# What is the best way to get CPU utilization of EC2 instance using AWS command in Jenkins

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I am writing a Jenkins job to show CPU utilization on a particular time and my Jenkins job is capable of handling AWS command using AWS cli.

Is there a easy way I can get the CPU utilization?

Comment: Have a look at example listed on URL to get cloudwatch metrics using AWS cli: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudwatch/get-metric-statistics.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`aws get-metric-statistics` command to gives the CPU utilization for an EC2 instance.

See the below command which gives CPU utilization

```
aws cloudwatch get-metric-statistics --namespace AWS/EC2 --metric-name CPUUtilization  --period 3600 --statistics Maximum --dimensions Name=InstanceId,Value=${instance2} --start-time ${startTime} --end-time  ${endTime}
```